# Quick Explode particles show in the viewframe but don't show when rendered

Tags: rendering

I've added quick explode effects to an object. The particles show in the viewframe (including  the rendered view) but when I render the animation the object remains solid.

I previously animated the scene and the effect worked as it should and rendered in the animation but now, after making changes to the scene, it refuses to render the animation.

I created the file on my old computer and sent the file via email to open it in my new computer. Several things about the file changed when I did that, I think it may have caused this problem.
I tried deleting the effect and all keyframes for the object and applying quick explode again but that didn't fix things.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sKMHd-UX68sqjB3TgN-NJ1yNfjG-6hIM/view?usp=sharing

The object in concern is named A_Step.

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sKMHd-UX68sqjB3TgN-NJ1yNfjG-6hIM/view?usp=sharing